# Combining multiple date spans of different frequencies

Tags: c#, sql-server, grouping, intervals, frequency

An *order* consists of a *startDate* the starting date of the span, *endDate* the ending date of the span, *unitAmount* the number of units per delivery, *frequencyAmount* the number of times the units are delivered per frequency, and *frequencyId* the frequency of the delivery.  For example: From 2017-01-01 to 2017-04-01 6 units are delivered 5 times per week.  It covers 13 calendar weeks for (6*5) units per week resulting in a total of 390 units for the entire order.
Multiple orders can be created overlapping the same dates.  This is allowed due to it being impossible to write 2 orders of 1 unit 3 times per week and 5 units 1 times per week as a single order, also for different frequencies like 10 units 1 time per month.

Problem:  I can not figure out a way to validate that these orders do not go over certain set limits.  For example, I want to make sure the orders stay under 40 units total per month and I might have 4 orders overlapping each other of different date spans, units, and frequencies.
I thought to combine all the orders by calculating how many units in total each order has and what percentage of the order overlaps another order.  However, when I validating a larger frequency, say <1000 units per year, and my orders that I have combined are smaller.  I end up having to extrapolate and overestimating how many units are being called for.  (For example, orders than combine to be 200 units for a single month, it is okay since it is only for a single month, but if I figure the yearly amount from that (200*12) it is 1200 and over the 1000 unit limit, but in reality the total units might still be under.

```
Orders:
    |-----------------4 6x/week---------------|
                   |-------------8 1x/week-------------|
           |-------10 2x/month-------|

===========================================================
Combined Orders:
    |--a---|---b---|--------c--------|---d----|----e---|
```

I am checking if each span of the combined orders (a-e) are over any daily, weekly, monthly, or yearly limits.  Different units have different limits and I need to be able to validate at these different frequencies.

I feel like I am going about this the wrong way, I keep running into issues with this approach such as my overestimation when extrapolating.  Another issue, looking at my diagram, the 3rd order for 10 units 2 times per month (lets say the order is a month long), when combined, falls into 2 spans **b** and **c**.  The 10 units could have been delivered twice in **b**, none in **c** or 1 in each **b** and **c** or none in **b** and twice in **c**.  So if I am converting to a weekly amount to combine I have to assume the total units were delivered in both spans **b** and **c** in a worst case scenario which leads to overestimations.  If I figure out the the percentage of units per each span, it leads to underestimations.

Has anyone else faced a similiar issue or does anyone else think they have a solution to this problem?

Thanks

EDIT:  Another situation can occur, imagine a limit of 30 units per month:

```
Orders:
    |---10 units 2x/week---|       |---10 units 2x/week---|
2017-01-01                                           2017-01-31
===========================================================
Combined Orders:
    |--------20------------|       |----------20-----------|
```

In this case, it goes over the limit not due to overlaps.  This makes me believe that I will also have to calculate the amount of units in each month (or week, day, year) between the earliest startDate and the furthest endDate.  Unless there is a better way, but I have a feeling this is the only way.

Comment: In the real world, when you have your special case of 10 units per month combined with units per week, how do you decide when the limits apply? It seems like your issue is under-specified. The same thing could apply to combining daily and weekly orders. Also does daily include Saturday and Sunday? Let's say I have an order for 1 2x/daily and 5 3x/weekly and want to stay under 4x daily. Am I over?

Comment: @NetMage Thanks for the comment.  There are limits on certain types of units, unit A is limited to 12 per day, unit B is limited to 30 per week, unit C is limited to 20 per month, and unit D is limited to 1 per year as examples.  When validating I look at one unit type at a time with consideration to its valid limit (most of the time just 1 limit).  Daily does include Saturday and Sunday, any day of the week.  2 units per day + 5 units 3 x weekly would be over on the days the weekly order occurs (going up to 7 units per day on those days)

Comment: The way I see it the combined orders is just a means to check if you are not exceeding limits. Since the shortest limit-period is 1day you could get all orders to a common denominator (1day). Calculate units per day for each order (this will be a float value) and from there it should be quite easy to to calculate number of units in any given time frame limited by both order start/end and limit period start/end. Rounding may prove a bit tricky through.

Comment: Other (bruteforce) solution would be to explode orders so you get date-number of units pairs for all delivered units (preferably do this only once and save to db) and then it's a simple select count for a given daterange.

Comment: Thanks @Furmek for the ideas.  I don't quite follow your second comment, but I really like the idea of calculating the units to the lowest grain.  I was worried about rounding errors however, after trying it out it looks like it may work well for overlaps.  I do realize I have another issue.  For a limit of 30 units per month, if there's 20 units in the first week of the month and 20 units in the last week of the month.  They are not overlapping but exceed the limit, so I think I do have to calculate number of units for all applicable unit frequency limits for orders from min start to max end.

Comment: Bruteforce method: When new order is added (eg: 5 units per week for 3 weeks) your code would generate 3 entries in db: 1'st Friday - 5units, 2'nd Friday - 5units, 3rd Friday - 5units (should this be Friday or do you ship one unit each business day). Whenever you want to check if your limits are still met you would have to query db to count number of items within given time range. This approach avoids rounding problems but I don't know if it applies to your case as @NetMage brought up some valid questions about limits.

Comment: @Furmek Units can be delivered on any day within the date span and we do not always know when exactly they are delivered and can not get that information reliably. I tried to make the problem more generic, but here is some more detail if it helps: This is ordering a service for someone in need.  If someone is elderly or disabled and requires assistance we have service orders written for a personal care assistant to come and help them with their basic needs, say for 4 hours 5 times a week.  Or they might get meals on wheels delivered to them 1 meal/day.  Different services have different limits

Comment: That complicates things even further. First let me confirm: can you set two orders for the same item type with different time base (say 3 meals weekly and another 10meals monthly)? If that's possible and you do not know up front exact days of delivery you are left with some cases that will give different results basing on actual delivery date - week can span between two months.

Comment: @Furmek That is correct, and I think that is one of the big issues with this problem that makes it difficult to be accurate.  I was hoping there was a way to get around this, but I think the lack of data there prevents that.

Comment: Given Unit A limited to 12 per day, it seems like you have insufficient information to determine if the limit is exceeded if you have any weekly/monthly/yearly orders for Unit A. You would need to know exactly which day the orders are fulfilled to calculate a daily total properly. Otherwise you must either round up or down.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any way other then what @Furmek suggested in his 3rd comment.
The prototype of the solution is below.

```
-- Here we calculate daily unit amount for all orders that overlap a validation period.
-- [frequency] is in days
;WITH ValidationPeriodOrders AS(
SELECT ( unitAmount * frequencyAmount ) / [frequency] AS AvgDailyAmount
    -- Adjust order dates to be within Validation period
    CASE WHEN startDate < ValidationPeriodStart THEN ValidationPeriodStart ELSE startDate END AS OrderStart,
    CASE WHEN endDate > ValidationPeriodEnd THEN ValidationPeriodEnd ELSE endDate END AS OrderEnd
FROM Order
-- Look for orders that fall inside a validation period
WHERE endDate BETWEEN ValidationPeriodStart AND ValidationPeriodEnd
    OR startDate BETWEEN ValidationPeriodStart AND ValidationPeriodEnd
)
-- Get total units per validation period
SELECT SUM( AvgDailyAmount * DATEDIFF( dd, OrderStart, OrderEnd ))
FROM ValidationPeriodOrders
```

Since there is no (reliable) way to tell when an order was delivered I would suggest rounding down the number (rather than mathematical rounding).